# Is this possible for combining of two arrays, in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays *signatories* and *designations*. Designations array has delimiter `"|"` indicating that 1 signatory has 2 designations. I'd like to output if the element has 2 value in delimiter and 1 in other array . It will produce another copy or clone. Like this.

```
$signatories = array('Allan','Robert','Maria');

$designations = array('CEO','CEO|COO','MANAGER|OIC|COO');
```

My expected output:

```
Allan - CEO

Robert - CEO
Robert - COO

Maria - MANAGER
Maria - OIC
Maria- COO
```

Comment: it would be sensible to change the source data if you have control over it

Comment: i'd like to point out that while doing it in a single loop is a cool trick, you now lose the ability to do any kind of validation or alteration and also make your code a bit more terse and hard to follow.  the cost to maintain code is often more expensive than minor performance gains that really never come into play in real life.

Answer (score 2):

You need two loops and can use the same index.

```
$signatories = array('Allan|Joshua|Ronald', 'Robert|Mellisa', 'Maria');
$designations = array('CEO','CEO|COO','MANAGER|OIC|COO');

$cs = count($signatories);
for ($i=0; $i<$cs; $i++) {
  $desigs = explode('|', $designations[$i]);
  $signas = explode('|', $signatories[$i]);
  foreach ($desigs as &$desig) {
    foreach ($signas as &$signa) {
      echo $signa.' - '.$desig.'<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: foreach and for, why 2 different loops? never put count() as the 2nd argument in a for loop, you run it on every loop

Comment: @dagon i avoid double quotes that don't have variables embedded for just such performance edges. i'll keep in mind what you are putting down there, thx.

Comment: @WEBjuju Hi sir, I loved the output, i have my part 2 of this question.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799723/is-this-possible-for-combining-of-two-arrays-part2-php

could you help me, how to execute this? thanks

Comment: @dafnycruz i have updated it for the other explode action that explains the answer for dagon about why we make code easy to edit

Comment: What is the purpose of the `&` writeback in the two `foreach` loops?

Comment: @halfer The & causes memory savings; rather than open up a new memory space for the current variable in the loop, the loop points directly at the memory space within the array being looped over.

Comment: Ah right @WEBjuju, thanks, hadn't thought of that. In practice an `isset()` would be good at the end of the loop - if one reuses that variable for some other purpose, it will faithfully writeback to the end of the array - a common cause of bugs when using this feature!

Answer (score 0):

Using foreach loop and explode() function you can combine both array in a single array.

```
    $signatories = array('Allan','Robert','Maria');

    $designations = array('CEO','CEO|COO','MANAGER|OIC|COO');

    $combinedArray = array();
    foreach($signatories as $key => $value){
        $combinedArray[] = array('name' => $value, 'designations' => explode("|",$designations[$key]));
    }
    print_r($combinedArray);die;
```

$combinedArray array has both name and array of designations.

Output of this array -

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Allan
            [designations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CEO
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Robert
            [designations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CEO
                    [1] => COO
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Maria
            [designations] => Array
                (
                    [0] => MANAGER
                    [1] => OIC
                    [2] => COO
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: You can use array_combine function and later on explode the elements by pipe sign.

Comment: Yes, we can use array_combine but atleast need a loop to join both array. That why i am using loop.

Answer (score 0):

Bit messy but , with one loop.

```
<?php

$signatories = array('Allan','Robert','Maria');
$designations = array('CEO','CEO|COO','MANAGER|OIC|COO');

$i = 0;
foreach($designations as $designation) {

    $newArr = explode('|',$designation);
    echo $signatories[$i].' - '.implode('<br>'.$signatories[$i].' - ',$newArr).'<br><br>';

$i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Another way,

```
$signatories = array('Allan','Robert','Maria');
$designations = array('CEO','CEO|COO','MANAGER|OIC|COO');


foreach($signatories as $key=>$val)
{  
   $exp = explode('|',$designations[$key]);
    foreach($exp as $dsg)
    {
        echo $val.' - '.$dsg;
        echo "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

and your Output will be,

```
Allan - CEO

Robert - CEO
Robert - COO

Maria - MANAGER
Maria - OIC
Maria - COO
```