# Is this possible for combining of two arrays in PHP? (part 2)

Tags: php, arrays

This is my part2 of my question, [following part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40797142/is-this-possible-for-combining-of-two-arrays-php?noredirect=1#comment68816359_40797142).

I have two arrays signatories and designations. Signatories and Designations arrays have delimiter `"|"` indicating that each have 1,2 or more signatories same as in designations,  depends on how many delimiter. I'd like to output if the element has 1, 2 or more values in delimiter and in other array . It will produce another copy or clone. Like this:

```
$signatories = array('Allan|Joshua|Ronald' , 'Robert|Mellisa' , 'Maria');

$designations = array('CEO|OIC' , 'CEO|COO|MANAGER' , 'MANAGER|OIC|COO');
```

My Expected Output:

```
***Array [0]***

Allan - CEO
Joshua - CEO
Ronald- CEO
Allan - OIC
Joshua - OIC
Ronald- OIC

***Array [1]***

Robert - CEO
Mellisa - CEO
Robert - COO
Mellisa - COO
Robert - MANAGER
Mellisa - MANAGER

***Array [2]***

Maria - MANAGER
Maria - OIC
Maria- COO
```

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow is not intended as a place where you can set out an order for free code. Thus, for your two questions, would you show what you have tried and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1):

A functional approach (easist to understand if read from behind/buttom-up):

```
$signatories = array('Allan|Joshua|Ronald', 'Robert|Mellisa', 'Maria');
$designations = array('CEO|OIC','CEO|COO','MANAGER|OIC|COO');

$result = array_map(function ($names, $titles) {
  return call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(function ($name) use ($titles) {
    return array_map(function ($title) use ($name) {
      return $name . ' - ' . $title;
    }, explode('|', $titles));
  }, explode('|', $names)));
}, $signatories, $designations);
```

This produces a result like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Allan - CEO
            [1] => Allan - OIC
            [2] => Joshua - CEO
            [3] => Joshua - OIC
            [4] => Ronald - CEO
            [5] => Ronald - OIC
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Robert - CEO
            [1] => Robert - COO
            [2] => Mellisa - CEO
            [3] => Mellisa - COO
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Maria - MANAGER
            [1] => Maria - OIC
            [2] => Maria - COO
        )

)
```

This solution uses built-in PHP functions to solve the problem:

1. First, the two arrays are "zipped" together with `array_map`.
2. Then for each name it is combined with each title in the pair.
3. Lastly, the array is flattened.

PHP doesn't have an array flatten function that is what this is for:

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', $input);
```

You could also look into using [RecursiveIterator from SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$signatories = array('Allan|Joshua|Ronald' , 'Robert|Mellisa' , 'Maria');

$designations = array('CEO|OIC' , 'CEO|COO|MANAGER' , 'MANAGER|OIC|COO');

if (count($signatories) > count($designations))
    Die("Sorry, but number of signatories is larger than number of designations, cannot continue.");

$result = [];
foreach ($signatories as $k => $v) {
    $subresult = [];
    $e = explode('|', $v);
    $e2 = explode('|', $designations[$k]);
    foreach ($e as $name) {
        foreach ($e2 as $designation) {
            $subresult[] = $name.' - '.$designation;    
        }

    }
    $result[] = $subresult;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$signatories = array('Allan|Joshua|Ronald' , 'Robert|Mellisa' , 'Maria');

$designations = array('CEO|OIC' , 'CEO|COO|MANAGER' , 'MANAGER|OIC|COO');

foreach($signatories as $key=>$item){
    $itemSet = explode('|', $item);
    foreach($itemSet as $row){
        $desSet = explode('|', $designations[$key]);
        foreach($desSet as $pos){
            echo $row." - ".$pos;
            echo "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two loops and can use the same index.

```
$signatories = array('Allan|Joshua|Ronald', 'Robert|Mellisa', 'Maria');
$designations = array('CEO|OIC', 'CEO|COO|MANAGER', 'MANAGER|OIC|COO');

$cs = count($signatories);
for ($i=0; $i<$cs; $i++) {
  $desigs = explode('|', $designations[$i]);
  $signas = explode('|', $signatories[$i]);
  foreach ($desigs as &$desig) {
    foreach ($signas as &$signa) {
      echo $signa.' - '.$desig.'<br>';
    }
  }
}
```